# Can't get PHP session save handler sqlite working

Tags: sqlite, session, php

I have set up a little server on an old XP Pro box, with php 5.3.1.
In order to use it as a test box to mirror our hosted site, I need to get sqlite sessions working.

While sqlite is definitely there in phpinfo(), I can't seem to get php.ini to use it as a save handler:
[Registered save handlers - files user](http://thegarbot.com/php.php)

In php.ini, I've got
    `session.save_handler = sqlite`
    `session.save_path = "D:\temp\php-session"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the system variable PHPRC not being read for some reason.  My php.ini was being ignored.

Found this out by going thru and redoing EVERYTHING over again to make sure I hadn't misconfigured something somewhere.  I didn't *see* any difference between the old and new var, but after a reboot things were suddenly coming up roses.

Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

A good question to have answered first is, does the SQLite plugin you're using expose itself as sqlite or sqlite3?

You may try using sqlite3 as your session.save_handler value. Make sure you start your sessions, too!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use SQLite as a session handler, two options :

1. It's registered as a session handler (you can check this in the phpinfo() > Registered save handlers). Usually it's "User, files" which means that you can't use SQLite as a session handler directly.
2. You can write your own session handler by implementing [session_ set_save _handler()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). An example is given in the manual.